# How to connect with boost::asio to a HTTPS server using a proxy?

Tags: ssl, boost, https, proxy, asio

In our application we use boost::asio to connect using HTTP and HTTPS. We also can use a HTTP proxy.
Now i need to add support for a HTTPS server using a proxy.

I studied quite a few samples and find that the needed steps seem to be:

1. Create a HTTP Connection to the Proxy
2. Send `CONNECT myhost.com:443` to the Proxy
3. Then continue using the connection as a SSL tunnel

The problem i am facing lies in STEP 3. I can EITHER connect using unencrypted HTTP OR connect using SSL/HTTPS. If i use a HTTPS connection before the handshake (in order to send CONNECT) that fails as well as performing a SSL handshake for a plain HTTP connection.

This post here contains some fragments - but it does not contain the step i am missing:
[Connect SSL server via HTTP proxy using boost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44939973/connect-ssl-server-via-http-proxy-using-boost)

Any hints what i am missing?

Sample code:

```
using boost::asio::ip::tcp;
namespace ssl = boost::asio::ssl;
typedef ssl::stream<tcp::socket> ssl_socket;

// Create a context that uses the default paths for
// finding CA certificates.
ssl::context ctx(ssl::context::sslv23);
ctx.set_default_verify_paths();


// Open a socket and connect it to the remote host.
boost::asio::io_context io_context;
ssl_socket socket(io_context, ctx);
boost::asio::connect(socket.lowest_layer(), resolver.resolve(query));
socket.lowest_layer().set_option(tcp::no_delay(true));
socket.set_verify_callback(ssl::host_name_verification(...));
boost::system::error_code error = boost::asio::error::host_not_found;

boost::asio::streambuf request2;
std::ostream request_stream2(&request2);

boost::asio::streambuf response2;

request_stream2 << "CONNECT " << in_server << ":443 HTTP/1.0\r\n";
request_stream2 << "Host: " << in_server << ":443 \r\n";
AddBasicUserAuthHeader(request_stream2, testUrl);
request_stream2 << "Proxy-Connection: keep-alive\r\n";
request_stream2 << "Connection: keep-alive\r\n\r\n";

// Send the request - this will fail with "write: uninitialized"
boost::asio::write(socket, request);

... wait and process response
socket.set_verify_mode(ssl::verify_none);
socket.handshake(ssl_socket::client);
```

This code fails in boost::asio::write with "write: uninitialized".
I can not figure out how to use the connection as plain HTTP/TCP at this point.
The other way round - first create a plain HTTP connection fails when trying to switch to HTTPS.

Comment: What step are you missing? What steps from the linked answer are you using? How are you using it? We're not psychics we can't tell if you don't show it.

Comment: @sehe - i added some sample code - which does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oof. That's some spotty code. Cleaning up the missing stuff and misspelled stuff, I noticed:

- you might need to explicitly or implicitly flush the ostream (just good practice really)
- you're writing to an ssl stream before the handshake? Just write to the underlying socket if you wanted:

  ```
   boost::asio::write(socket, request);
  ```

  Should be

  ```
   boost::asio::write(socket.next_layer(), request);
  ```

That said, I'd probably not construct the ssl stream until you have a proxy response. I'd also write the request using Beast to rule out any mishaps in dealing with the implementation details manually.

---

**[Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6c12bc92e8b1f876)**

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/ssl.hpp>
#include <boost/beast.hpp>
#include <boost/beast/ssl.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using boost::asio::ip::tcp;
namespace ssl      = boost::asio::ssl;
namespace beast    = boost::beast;
namespace http     = beast::http;
using ssl_socket   = ssl::stream<tcp::socket>;
using Request      = http::request<http::empty_body>;
using Response     = http::response<http::empty_body>;
using BodyResponse = http::response<http::string_body>;

int main()
{
    std::string const in_server = "example.com";
    boost::asio::io_context io_context;
    tcp::resolver           resolver(io_context);
    tcp::resolver::query    query{"localhost", "8888"};

    // Create a context that uses the default paths for
    // finding CA certificates.
    ssl::context ctx(ssl::context::sslv23);
    ctx.set_default_verify_paths();

    // Open a socket and connect it to the remote host.
    ssl_socket socket(io_context, ctx);
    boost::asio::connect(socket.lowest_layer(), resolver.resolve(query));
    socket.lowest_layer().set_option(tcp::no_delay(true));
    socket.set_verify_callback(ssl::host_name_verification(in_server));

    {
        Request request(http::verb::connect, in_server + ":443", 10);

        request.set(http::field::host, in_server+":443");
        request.set(http::field::proxy_connection, "keep-alive");
        request.set(http::field::connection, "keep-alive");
        request.set(http::field::proxy_authorization, "basic aGVsbG86d29ybGQ=");
        request.prepare_payload(); // no body, but still good practice

        // Send the request
        http::write(socket.next_layer(), request);
    }

    Response proxy_response;
    //... wait and process response
    {
        http::response_parser<http::empty_body> p;
        beast::flat_buffer                      buf;
        // Only headers expected
        http::read_header(socket.next_layer(), buf, p);

        proxy_response = std::move(p.get());

        assert(buf.size() == 0); // no excess data should be received
    }

    std::cout << proxy_response << "\n";
    if (proxy_response.result() == http::status::ok) {
        socket.set_verify_mode(ssl::verify_none);
        socket.handshake(ssl_socket::client);
        std::cout << "Handshake completed" << std::endl;
    } else {
        return 1; // TODO handle errors
    }

    {
        Request request(http::verb::get, "/", 10);
        request.set(http::field::host, in_server);
        http::write(socket, request);
    }

    {
        beast::flat_buffer buf;
        BodyResponse       http_res;
        http::read(socket, buf, http_res);
        std::cout << http_res;
    }
}
```

On my machine prints

```
HTTP/1.0 200 Connection established
Proxy-agent: tinyproxy/1.8.4


Handshake completed
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Age: 214958
Cache-Control: max-age=604800
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date: Mon, 25 Oct 2021 23:11:37 GMT
Etag: "3147526947+gzip+ident"
Expires: Mon, 01 Nov 2021 23:11:37 GMT
Last-Modified: Thu, 17 Oct 2019 07:18:26 GMT
Server: ECS (bsa/EB23)
Vary: Accept-Encoding
X-Cache: HIT
Content-Length: 1256
Connection: close

<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Example Domain</title>

    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <style type="text/css">
    body {
        background-color: #f0f0f2;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        font-family: -apple-system, system-ui, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", "Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        
    }
    div {
        width: 600px;
        margin: 5em auto;
        padding: 2em;
        background-color: #fdfdff;
        border-radius: 0.5em;
        box-shadow: 2px 3px 7px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.02);
    }
    a:link, a:visited {
        color: #38488f;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    @media (max-width: 700px) {
        div {
            margin: 0 auto;
            width: auto;
        }
    }
    </style>    
</head>

<body>
<div>
    <h1>Example Domain</h1>
    <p>This domain is for use in illustrative examples in documents. You may use this
    domain in literature without prior coordination or asking for permission.</p>
    <p><a href="https://www.iana.org/domains/example">More information...</a></p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Added a fixed/cleaned example that I tested with [tinyproxy](http://tinyproxy.github.io/) on Ubuntu

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply and sample code. You are using bosst::beast - which so far i hadn't tried. But yes - that works.

Comment: There is no difference except it's less work. There's no magic in Beast, certainly nothing relevant to the question.